# iOS App Extension javascript arguments undefined after CompleteRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am making an `iOS Action App Extension` and I am unable to access data in the `finalize()` function in javascript file after calling `CompleteRequest` method in monotouch. The run() method in my javascript file works fine because I'm able to get the page url just like in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1).

Here's is my code :

```
NSDictionary itemData = new NSDictionary(new NSString("bgColor"),new NSString("red"));

var resultsDictionary = new NSDictionary(NSJavaScriptExtension.FinalizeArgumentKey, itemData);

var resultsProvider = new NSItemProvider(resultsDictionary, "kUTTypePropertyList");

var resultsItem = new NSExtensionItem();
resultsItem.Attachments = new NSItemProvider[] { resultsProvider };

ExtensionHelper.ExtensionContext.CompleteRequest(new NSExtensionItem[] { resultsItem }, null);
```

In my javascript file :

```
var MyExtensionJavaScriptClass = function() {};

MyExtensionJavaScriptClass.prototype = {
     run: function(arguments) {
         // This works completely fine
         arguments.completionFunction({"baseURI": document.baseURI});
     },
     finalize: function(arguments) {
         console.log(arguments["bgColor"]); // Undefined
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = arguments["bgColor"];
     }
};

var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new MyExtensionJavaScriptClass;
```

When I dump the arguments variable of the finalize function into the console it looks like an empty object :

```
Object

    __defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() {
    __defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() {
    __lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() {
    __lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() {
    constructor: function Object() {
    hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() {
    isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() {
    propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() {
    toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() {
    toString: function toString() {
    valueOf: function valueOf() {
    __proto__: Object
```

Here's what the simulator system.log contains :

```
MobileSafari[64987]: completed request - items: (
        "<NSExtensionItem: 0x7d798940> - userInfo: {\n    NSExtensionItemAttachmentsKey =     (\n        \"<NSItemProvider: 0x7d78f910> {types = (\\n    kUTTypePropertyList\\n)}\"\n    );\n}"
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the Xamarin.iOS [documentation on app extensions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/intro_to_app_extensions/offline.pdf) has some invalid code.

If you look at a couple examples in [Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/16/6/hacking-with-javascript-uitextview), you can see they don't use `"kUTTypePropertyList"` as the identifier, but the constant `kUTTypePropertyList`. With a little bit of research, I  found the equivalent in Xamarin : `MobileCoreServices.UTType.PropertyList`. Replacing it will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help.